# split numbers into multiple PdfTextFormField in iTextPdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

What is a correct way to write a use case? Where I need to split a 8 character long code and map each character into corresponding PdfTextFormField. I have checked with PdfFormField, but that will map the whole text in the field.

Comment: If there are separate form fields for the separate characters of the code, why don't you simply set each of the fields to the respective code character?

Comment: I am capturing the input in a single input html element in UI. Now i have to split the same code into each boxes in PDF mapping.